# UIScrollViews and Dynamically Creating Pages

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uiscrollview, programmatically-created

I want to be able to dynamically populate `UIScrollView`. Like how it is done for row views in `UITableView`. I have a class that takes in some parameters and creates the respective view when it scrolls. Currently I have 8 views.

These 8 views have different background image, image and label according to the page number it is currently in. However the basic skeleton for this view is the same. What i am doing right now is in `ViewDidLoad` I am creating 8 views and add them as subviews and scroll over.

I don't want to do this. I want to create three views and the rest i want to populate when the user scrolls a page and then a page etc. How do i do this? ANy pointers/tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you calculate the ContentSize for the scrollview (when you want to use the iPad in landscapemode with 8 pages then the width should be 1024*8 = 8192px and the height 768px).

Then you should implement the UIScrollView Delegate method:

```
scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:
```

In this Method you check on which page you currently are with the contentOffset property of the scrollview and start updating your left and right hidden views..

Hope this helps you a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Check the two most recent WWDC videos for two excellent sessions regarding expert use of UIScrollViews. Additionally you can review a brief tutorial [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/multiple-virtual-pages-in-uiscrollview.html), written by the well known cocoa expert, Matt Gallagher.